# CSV Problems and Help Needed with Code

Tags: python, excel, csv

So I am trying to create a Python script that will sort a specified column of an Excel sheet. So far my code is...

```
import csv
import operator

with open('case_name.csv') as infile:
    data = list(csv.reader(infile, dialect=csv.excel_tab))

data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2))

with open('case_name_sorted.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, dialect='excel')
    writer.writerows(data)
```

However, when I run this code I continue to get an error that says...

```
data = list(csv.reader(infile, dialect=csv.excel_tab))
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

I did some research and found out that .csv files do not work well on a Mac. So what should I change the file to that will keep it working like an Excel sheet? Also, if anyone has any pointers on how else I could sort a column, I would very much appreciate some tips. Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve this? If not, can you share your specific error that happened after you opened it with rU?

Answer (score 0):

try opening the file with the mode

```
open('case_name.csv', mode='rU')
```

compare with: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: I get an error that says the list index is out of range

Comment: so the reading seems to work. did you have a look at your `data`? do you know what `data` looks like when the error occurs?